# Exchange-server and archived elements

Tags: exchange, archive

I notice that archived elements is stored locally on the computer.

But is it also stored on the exchange server?

Maclovin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the message Outlook presents about Archiving old items, then no, it is only stored locally. It simply creates the Archive.pst file.

Comment: Correct, that archive pst file is only stored locally on the machine it was made. Redgate and Sunbelt Software have Exchange email archiving solutions.